# Angular loading only sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, handlebars.js

Hi so I am getting a weird error while trying to use Angular.

when I visit the page with angular I sometimes get this js error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module trainingApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'trainingApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I can refresh the page and then angular loads the module and the page displays as intended, every time I refresh it loads correctly. It just seems to fail loading when I click on a link from the non angular page to an angular page.

Here is some code:

initiating my app in the markup:

```
<div ng-app="trainingApp" ng-controller="listController">
```

and here is my angular app:

```
var app = angular.module('trainingApp', []);

app.config(['$interpolateProvider',function($interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
    }]);

app.controller('listController',['$scope','$http', '$log', function($scope, $http, $log) {
  $http.get('/ajax/seminar-list.php?q='+$("#seminarID").val()+'&t='+new Date().getTime())
    .success(function(data){
      if (data.length > 0)
      {
        $scope.lists = data;
        $(".listController").show();
      }
    });
  }]);
```

I have a feeling it might have to do with the interpolateProvider to change the template tags, the view gets rendered through mustache first so we changed the template tags to they dont disappear after mustache renders the template.

Any thoughts or help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Mind if i ask - Why are you using Mustache? Not sure if it's related to your issue, though Angular has its own template engine.

Comment: Yea I think that is the underlying issue... we haven't fully adopted angular yet so we were more experimenting. the mustache gets rendered serverside with php. I may need to rework some of this and adopt angular 100% or just go back and use jquery since this site isn't using much of angulars single page app powers much at all.

Comment: Where are you defining your angular code in the page? Maybe you just need to move it up to before the `ng-app` call.

Comment: I had this issue a lot while working with Apache Cordova a couple weeks ago. Never actually tried to discovered the cause.